# Using getters and setters to change another variable C#

Tags: c#, design-patterns

Is it a bad practice to use getters and setters this way?

Below is my code:

```
public struct Settings
{
    public static int workMinutes
    {
        get
        {
            return Properties.Settings.Default.workMinutes;
        }
        set
        {
            Properties.Settings.Default.workMinutes = value;
            save();
        }
    }

    public static int restMinutes
    {
        get
        {
            return Properties.Settings.Default.restMinutes;
        }
        set
        {
            Properties.Settings.Default.restMinutes = value;
            save();
        }
    }

    public static void init()
    {
        if(Properties.Settings.Default.workMinutes == 0)
            Properties.Settings.Default.workMinutes = 5;

        if(Properties.Settings.Default.restMinutes == 0)
            Properties.Settings.Default.restMinutes = 5;

        save();
    }

    private static void save()
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. I know you are eager to have your code reviewed. In CR, we expect a summary of what your code does ?

Comment: Making this a `struct` makes little sense, a value type is a *value*, not a façade for some static object; there is no immutable data to encapsulate here - IMO this should be a `class`, if it needs to exist at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's a bad practice at all. What you did is called encapsulation. It enables you to exchange the underlying configuration provider (currently the `Properties.Settings`) to something else without breaking your application because it doesn't rely directly on it.

It's also called the *Dependency Inversion Principle* the higher module (your application) relies on an abstraction (your `Settings`) and not on the low level module (`Properties.Settings`). Usually it's build upon abstract types (or interfaces) but a *lite* version of this could be your settings layer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see what you've done here as 'bad practice'. But I can suggest some improvements. My comments are below each snippet of your code:

```
public static int workMinutes
{
    get
    {
        return Properties.Settings.Default.workMinutes;
    }
    set
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default.workMinutes = value;
        save();
    }
}
```

Can the wrapped code possibly throw? If yes, can you include code that guards against those exceptions from throwing? If no, please document your getter/setter with the list of exceptions that could possibly throw, having a brief explanation as to what conditions can cause the exceptions.

```
public static void init()
{
    if(Properties.Settings.Default.workMinutes == 0)
        Properties.Settings.Default.workMinutes = 5;

    if(Properties.Settings.Default.restMinutes == 0)
        Properties.Settings.Default.restMinutes = 5;

    save();
}
```

You've created properties, but then in client code (the init method), you don't use the properties, but rather you directly access the thing being wrapped. I suggest that you use your properties in all client code.

```
private static void save()
{
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

I see no good reason to wrap the call to Properties.Settings.Default.Save inside of this static method. Your wrapper is private, and is consumed only by members of the same struct. I suggest to remove your custom save method, and making direct calls to Properties.Settings.Default.Save within the other two struct members.

Lemme know what you think about my critique.

Answer (score 1):

#### Naming Conventions

- Avoid *java* naming conventions `void save`. Use *C#* conventions instead `void Save`.
- Favor verbs `Initialise` over abbreviations `Init` for method names.

---

#### Type Conventions

- Don't use `struct` for mutable objects. Use `class` instead.

---

#### Design Considerations

Others have already pointed out `Settings` could be used as a facade for your application, splitting the interface from the internal implementation. Ideally, you would want to create an interface for your *settings providers* and have one implementation that uses the auto-generated `Properties.Settings` class. For the sake of limiting our scope, let's work directly on the auto-generated settings.

```
 public class Settings
    {
        private Properties.Settings settings;

        Settings(Properties.Settings settings)
        {
            this.settings = settings ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(settings));
        }
      
        // ..
    }
```

We could then write cleaner code with much less redudancy.

```
        public int WorkMinutes
        {
            get => settings.WorkMinutes;
            set
            {
                settings.WorkMinutes = value;
                Save();
            }
        }

        public int RestMinutes
        {
            get => settings.RestMinutes;
            set
            {
                settings.RestMinutes = value;
                Save();
            }
        }
```

You no longer have a static class, but perhaps you would like a shared instance available throughout your application. Let's forsee a shared instance.

```
private static Settings shared;
public static Settings Default => shared ?? (shared = new Settings(Properties.Settings.Default));
```

Perhaps we could auto-initialise our settings in the constructor.

```
 Settings(Properties.Settings settings)
        {
            this.settings = settings ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(settings));
            Initialise();
        }
```

---

#### Extended Design

In a real application, it's likely `Settings` would end containing dozens of seperate settings properties. Perhaps the settings would also be editable at runtime. In addition, `Initialise` would have to call `Save` on each individual property. We could use a batch update on demand to optimize our class.

`Initialise` would look like this:

```
 public void Initialise()
 {
     using (var batch = new Batch(this))
     {
         if (WorkMinutes == 0)
         {
             WorkMinutes = 5;
         }

         if (RestMinutes == 0)
         {
             RestMinutes = 5;
         }

         // other settings ..

     } // <- this calls Save() once
 }
```

The pattern can be implemented as follows:

```
        private void Save()
        {
            if (!deferred)
            {
                settings.Save();
            }
        }

        private bool deferred;

        public IDisposable StartBatch()
        {
            return new Batch(this);
        }

        private class Batch : IDisposable
        {
            Settings source;

            public Batch(Settings source)
            {
                Debug.Assert(source != null);
                this.source = source;
                this.source.deferred = true;
            }

            public void Dispose()
            {
                source.deferred = false;
                source.Save();
            }
        }
```